# tcsh closes file descriptors

Tags: tcsh, file-descriptors

I have a program that is being launched with a tcsh script. I would like to communicate with that process trough pipes (*not* named pipes) created by a parent process.
However, it looks like tcsh closes every open pipe except `0-2` when starting up.

Example (might be slightly longer than needed, problem is visible as soon as `B''`):

For "clarity", I will identify bash prompts with `$`, and tcsh ones with `%`. I increment the letter when the process is a fork, and add a `'` to mark an `exec (3)` call.

```
A$ exec 42>42_output.txt # open fd 42
A$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  2  255  3  42
A$ bash # launch bash as a child
B$ echo test >&42 #writes "test" to the file
B$ exec bash
B'$ echo test2 >&42 # also writes to the file
B'$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  2  255  3  42
B'$ tcsh
B''% ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  15  16  17  18  19  2
B''% bash
C$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  2  255  3
C$ exit
B''% exec bash
B'''$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  2  255  3
A$ exit
A$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  2  255  3  42
A$ exec tcsh
A$ ls /proc/$$/fd
0  1  15  16  17  18  19  2  4
```

The file descriptor is closed, which means that I cannot use it anymore from the child process. Is there any way to tell csh to persist (avoid closing) file descriptors?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299440/108618)? Where it says `[tcsh] does not provide the script writer with a way to manipulate numbered file descriptors`.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen it, but assumed it didn't apply, due to its title. I am a bit unsure where it happens, but it is pretty clear that [tcsh closes fds on exit by design](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/91827aa5e4d771308dd55168fc2c817c45252d62/sh.exec.c#L220) [and before executing a file](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/5ce0343b3505046e42ddd95417c6884cca5a2563/sh.misc.c#L310). it talks about [moving them to a safe place](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/7a42e6029ac50c2925275d39786638d09351446e/sh.c#L477), but is pretty unclear what that safe place is...

Comment: ...or if we can have them back. The code is a bit unclear with variable such has `didfds` not having an explicit role, and there not being a lot of comments. (sorry for posting two comments, the links were quite long).